# How to create a b-tree index in google bigtable

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-platform, bigtable

I want to store spatiotemporal data in Google BigTable using Hilbert curves. For making the queries more efficient, I can use indexing methods (such as b-trees). Is there a way that I can specify which indexing method I want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Bigtable is indexed by `rowKey` in lexicographical order.  That is the only indexing method that is supported.